# Is it possible to Iterate over a guava Cache in order of insertion/access?

Tags: java, dictionary, caching, guava

I'm trying to use a Guava Cache as a replacement for the [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/). However I found that while the ConcurrentLinkedHashMap allowed me to iterate over the map in order of Insertion, Guava's `asMap()` method doesn't return elements in any particular order. Am I missing something, or is this functionality simply not available?

Example (trying to print the keys, the values, and the entries):

```
Cache<Integer, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(10).initialCapacity(10)
        .expireAfterAccess(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

cache.put(1, 1);
cache.put(2, 2);
cache.put(3, 3);
cache.put(4, 4);
cache.put(5, 5);
cache.put(6, 6);

Iterator<Integer> iter1 = cache.asMap().keySet().iterator();

System.out.println("Keys");
while (iter1.hasNext())
    System.out.println(iter1.next());

System.out.println("Values");
Iterator<Integer> iter2 = cache.asMap().values().iterator();

while (iter2.hasNext())
    System.out.println(iter2.next());

System.out.println("Entries");
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter3 = cache.asMap().entrySet().iterator();

while (iter3.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer,Integer> entry = iter3.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Prints:

```
Keys
2
6
1
4
3
5
Values
2
6
1
4
3
5
Entries
2 2
6 6
1 1
4 4
3 3
5 5
```

Comment: Good question, and it looks like the answer is "no"... You can implement your own `Cache` but not use it in a `CacheBuilder`...

Comment: Implementing my own Cache means duplicating the ordering information the Guava Cache already keeps. This seems awkward.

Comment: `Cache` is an interface. And Guava's caches, AFAICS, don't guarantee ordering information at all. What I meant is that you could implement `Cache` so that the underlying map is a `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap`; right now it is a derivate of `ConcurrentHashMap`. But again, even if you do that, I don't see how you can use that in a `CacheBuilder`, so...

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you meant extending the existing LoadingCache. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CacheWriter` will allow your code to be invoked during an explicit write or on removal. For a loading cache, you would have to perform the same work within the loader. That too is performed under the entry's lock so you can assume atomicity. This should let you maintain the ordering without relying on the cache's internal data structures. Note that if the work when performing the ordered iteration is expensive, you might want to copy it inside the lock and then do the work outside so as not to block cache writes.

```
LinkedHashMap<K, V> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LoadingCache<K, V> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .writer(new CacheWriter<K, V>() {
      public void write(K key, V value) {
        synchronized (orderedMap) {
          orderedMap.put(key, value);
        }
      }
      public void delete(K key, V value, RemovalCause cause) {
        if (cause == RemovalCause.REPLACED) {
          return;
        }
        synchronized (orderedMap) {
          orderedMap.remove(key);
        }
      }
    })
    .maximumSize(1_000)
    .build(key -> {
        V value = ...
        synchronized (orderedMap) {
          orderedMap.put(key, value);
        }
        return value;
    });

cache.put(key1, value); // calls writer under lock
cache.get(key2); // calls loader under lock; not writer
cache.invalidate(key1); // calls writer under lock
cache.policy().eviction().get().setMaximum(0); // calls writer under lock

synchronized (orderedMap) {
  for (K key : orderedMap.keySet()) {
    // do work, but blocks writes!
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, that's an nice approach. Plus the locking could be improved by using more than one lock, and possibly using a ReadWrite lock to allow multiple readers.

Comment: Unfortunately read/write locks are usually [worse](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/02/11/readerwriter-locks-and-their-lack-of-applicability-to-finegrained-synchronization/), unless you have long hold times due to I/O.

Comment: Sure, it's something I'll need to actually benchmark.

Comment: It took a while, but I finally benchmarked a bunch of Java locking mechanisms (https://github.com/maltalex/JavaLockBenchmark). You're were right about the performance of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, but in Java 8+, if reentrant locking isn't important, `ReentrantReadWriteLock` can be replaced by the much more performant `StampedLock` which outperforms every other locking mechanism.

Comment: @Malt `StampedLock` is much definitely better, but is optimistic and doesn't block. That's perfect for in-memory calls, wasteful for expensive I/O calls. In either case you have to be mindful that reads have no side-effects, e.g. LRU reorders on access so a read/write lock doesn't work as it is always an unsafe mutation.

Comment: `StampedLock` can block - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html#readLock--
What do you mean by "wasteful"?

Comment: @Malt A reader optimistically performs the work and checks the stamp to validate, retrying if the stamp was modified. A writer is a spin lock on the stamp. This is known as `busy waiting` and is inefficient for long operations where you can block, letting the cpu be used for other work.

Comment: I didn't dive into the internals of `StampedLock`, it's a complicated class. But my stack traces show that threads waiting on `StampedLock.writeLock()` or `StampedLock.readLock()` end up being parked, not busy waiting. Unless of course `StampedLock.tryOptimisticRead()` is used, uses busy waiting explicitly. So I'm curious what the downsides of `StampledLock` are, and why it's not used more often. If you have insights into that, I'd be happy to chat or open a separate question on this topic.

Comment: @Malt Oh you're right, I forgot that it supported a blocking mode. That shows how rarely I've used it! I suppose the downsides are that it is not reentrant and lacks conditions. Almost all cases that I've seen read/write locks used could be done more efficiently without them, so I suppose it is because neither are commonly used.

Comment: Thing is, the benchmark shows that `StampedLock` outperforms all other locks even in the 100% writers case where locks are exclusive. This even includes locking using the `synchronized` monitor. So yeah, the lack of support of reentrance can hurt, especially if you have callbacks. But for many use cases it looks like a free performance win.

Comment: @Malt You might be right. However it may not matter when you writing high performance code that avoids lock contention on the hot paths. The cold paths might lock, but if designed to not contend so it doesn't matter. In those cases locking is not the dominant cost. For example `computeIfAbsent` could be implemented as a lock-free read when present, but on a miss locks and performs a db query. There are quirks like biased locking interfering with GC safe points, which could be making `synchronized` more complex and hurt its performance. Definitely a nice reminder to use StampedLock more often.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question)

It seems fge's answer is correct, and the Guava Cache cannot be iterated according to the order of insertion. As a workaround, I used the previously noted [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/), which is less feature rich, but allows for ordered iteration.

I'd still appreciate an official answer from someone on the Guava team since this seems to indicate that the ConcurrentLinkedHashMap is not fully integrated into Guava (contrary to the ConcurrentLinkedHashMap documentation)

Comment: Official answer: we have no plans for adding this feature to Guava - sorry!

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: This is now available in the Java 8 rewrite, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), through the [policy api](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Policy).

Comment: @BenManes I've just ran into the same use case again and recalled this question. How does Caffeine provide insertion-order iteration? I haven't been able find it in the API.

Comment: @Malt See `cache.policy()` for low level details like eviction or expiration order. You might instead maintain your own order since it is not strictly access or inserted order

Comment: @BenManes The question is about iterating over all current elements according to insertion order. How is that achievable through the eviction/expiration tuning exposed by the policy api? I feel like I'm missing something. Would you like me to open a separate question about that?

Comment: `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` didn't allow that, only in order of eviction (which is access order in LRU). TTL expiration is ordered by insert or update, making it a hack. I don't think a cache can be expected to provide a strongly ordered traversal so probably not possible in the APIs.

Comment: @BenManes Iterating according to insertion order is what the original (?) LinkedHashMap in the JDK provides via its linked list which (javadoc) "defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map". It makes sense for LRU caches in some cases. Do you know of anything out that that can do this, and do this well?

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` would, but if as a cache then it is a FIFO policy. If you set to LRU (access order) then it will iterate in that order. Usually one doesn't use LHM as a cache and rely upon its iteration order for application logic, due to concurrency. When its available for free (same linked list) then its okay to expose, so we did that in CLHM and Caffeine. I don't know of any caching library that maintains insertion order independently of the eviction policy, mostly as more complexity that is rarely used. You could maintain it yourself using a `CacheWriter` and LHM, right?

Comment: @BenManes I wrote "LRU" when I meant FIFO, as in `expireAfterWrite`.

Comment: @Malt I added an answer with some example code. I hope that helps.