# Are there any data structures which preserves iteration order and also drop old records?

Tags: java, data-structures, guava

I have a use case where I want to populate entries into a data structure from multiple threads so it has to be thread safe and after a particular size is reached start dropping old records. And I also want to iterate over the data structure in the same order of Insertion.

So I decided to use `Guava Cache` here but to my surprise Guava `asMap()` method doesn't return elements in any particular order.

```
private final Cache<Integer, Integer> cache =
      CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(10)
          .removalListener(
              RemovalListeners.asynchronous(new CustomListener(), executorService)
          ).build();

cache.put(1, 1);
cache.put(2, 2);
cache.put(3, 3);
cache.put(4, 4);
cache.put(5, 5);
cache.put(6, 6);

for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : cache.asMap().entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

**Output:**

```
2=2
6=6
1=1
4=4
3=3
5=5
```

What other efficient data structure I can use here which can preserve the iteration order for me and also **reliably** drop old records as soon as the size is reached and have some callback for the removal listener where I can figure out what records are getting dropped?

Any example will be of great help. I am using Java 7 and cannot switch to Java 8 yet.

So I should be able to get something like this while iterating and also it should drop old records automatically:

```
1=1
2=2
3=3
4=4
5=5
6=6
```

Comment: Can you talk more about how you want to access the elements in the data structure? Would that be in order? By key? Randomly? At the front?

Comment: In the same order it was inserted so `1 and 1` was inserted first so I want to get that first while iterating. Edited the question.

Comment: so the only way you are ever grabbing from the data structure is to iterate to it? you could use a queue data structure

Comment: Yes. btw are there any  other ways also grabbing from the data structure? Just curious.

Comment: yes, things like a Hashmap are ways of pairing things together for quick lookup

Comment: There are evething you need in Guava Cache BUT the ordering. Take a look here: http://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache and on this answer which has an official member mention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966778/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-a-guava-cache-in-order-of-insertion-access The first link will provide almost everything you need.

Comment: Yes I saw that but I need ordering right so first link might not provide me what I am looking for?

Comment: Since you can't use Java 8 (and hence `Caffeine`), and `Guava Cache` does most of what you want, perhaps you could manually populate a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`/`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` based on a `CacheLoader.load` and `RemovalListener.onRemoval`... ??

Comment: @BrianKent interesting... can you provide an example of how that would work out? I am not sure fully how this will work here so an example will help me to understand better.

Comment: You have multiple threads inserting.  How does that affect "insertion order"?  Do the threads communicate between each other?  That is, does the order among all threads matter, or just the inserts for a single thread?  Note that concurrency may make apparent order very different, especially in fully optimized code.  Can writes from one thread push out everything from a different thread, or only its own previous writes?

Comment: The suggestions of using a synchronized, bounded `LinkedHashMap` appear the best fit. One would assume you want a FIFO cache, e.g. not an LRU with insertion iteration (a confusing need). Its unusual for a fifo cache to need high read concurrency, so LHM should be fine. If you do, though, an efficient implementation is easy to code by using lock on write, wrapping values as linked list nodes, using a volatile `next` field, and having the iterator walk the node `next` fields. But, I highly doubt that's useful which is why you won't see that data structure somewhere on github.

Answer (score 2):

For Java 7 you can use [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)'s predecessor, [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap):

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> cache =
        new ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder<Integer, Integer>()
                .maximumWeightedCapacity(10)
                .build();

cache.put(1, 1);
cache.put(2, 2);
cache.put(3, 3);
cache.put(4, 4);
cache.put(5, 5);
cache.put(6, 6);

for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

**Output**

```
1=1
2=2
3=3
4=4
5=5
6=6
```

See [ExampleUsage · ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap Wiki](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/ExampleUsage) for more details.

Comment: CLHM is access ordered, so this probably won't fit his needs. Its very unusual to want both a highly concurrent map and insertion order. That's easy to write, but usually not actually the need. Most likely a synchronized `LinkedHashMap` as a fifo cache is all he needs, with limited concurrency acceptable.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that it was access order. Thanks @BenManes.

Comment: @BenManes What is wrong with CLHM here? I thought this will suit me best? And I was mostly waiting for you to come and look at this question to give some feedback :)

Comment: @user5447339 The policy keeps order by access (LRU) which is challenging to do concurrently as every read is a write. But you want insertion order (FIFO), which is easy to do concurrently but has a very poor hit rate. Since high concurrency tends to mean non-deterministic access, iterating a ConcurrentMap in insertion-order rarely makes sense. That's why you wont see a version floating around Github or in wide use. Most often a LHM is good enough for those cases. I can help write one for you (easiest to chat over email), but I agree with others who suspect a LHM is a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

The common data structures that preserves iteration order are,

- queue
- deque
- linked list etc..

however, the solution that best fits your needs will be to use a **deque** which offers some built in functions such as,

`add(element)`: Adds an element to the tail.

`addFirst(element)`: Adds an element to the head.

`addLast(element)`: Adds an element to the tail.

`offer(element)`: Adds an element to the tail and returns a boolean to explain if the insertion was successful.

`offerFirst(element)`: Adds an element to the head and returns a boolean to 
explain if the insertion was successful.

`offerLast(element)`: Adds an element to the tail and returns a boolean to explain if the insertion was successful.

`iterator()`: Returna an iterator for this deque.

`descendingIterator()`: Returns an iterator that has the reverse order for this deque.

`push(element)`: Adds an element to the head.

`pop(element)`: Removes an element from the head and returns it.

`removeFirst()`: Removes the element at the head.

`removeLast()`: Removes the element at the tail.

For more on deque :https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/deque-util/java-util-deque-example/

Answer (score 0):

Given that you show `put(k, v)` in your example, I assume you also use this data structure for key-based lookups, so simple queues are not ideal.

In this case you can use a `LikedHashMap` wrapped by a `Collection.synchronized`, and implement the `removeEldest` method. The following example doesn't show multiple threads, but should work just fine with multiple threads. In order to perform your own computation on the items being removed, you implement the `entryRemoved` method in the subclass of `BoundedMap`:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Collections;

class BoundedMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  private final int capacity;

  public BoundedMap(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest){
    if(size() > capacity) {
      remove(eldest.getKey());
      entryRemoved(eldest);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void entryRemoved(Map.Entry<K,V> entry) {
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = Collections.synchronizedMap(
      new BoundedMap<Integer, Integer>(5) {
        @Override
        public void entryRemoved(Map.Entry entry) {
          System.out.println(entry);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("--- adding");
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
      m.put(i, -i);
    }
    System.out.println("-- iterating");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a simple subclass of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` that overrides `removeEldestEntry()`, as described in its [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry-java.util.Map.Entry-).